# Load settings from JSON file for mobile-config.js

Tags: jquery, json, facebook, cordova, meteor

I want to keep the settings for my FB app in one place in the meteor code. Now that I've added the mobile-config.js file for cordova integration, along with the native FB plugin, I need to put my FB app settings in two places. One in the Meteor Settings JSON and one in the mobile-config.js file. I'm trying to get the mobile-config.js file to just read the settings from the other JSON but am having trouble. Any ideas?

```
var $ = Npm.require('jquery');
$.getJSON('./private/config/settings.json', function(settings) {
  App.configurePlugin('com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect', {
    APP_ID: settings.public.fb.app_id,
    API_KEY: settings.private.fb.app_key,
  });
});


Error reading mobile-config.js:ReferenceError: Npm is not defined
```

Comment: The issue seems to steam from whatever is wrapping the mobile-config.js file has removed the require function from the global context. Do I need to get these settings from the process.env variable? I can't seem to find a way to require code in this context to load the JSON file.

Comment: did you ever get any info on this? I'm also interested.

Comment: I have not yet found a way to link the two settings files. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm also interested in case you ever figured this out